# Help required in some derivation

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Given :

$$f(k+1) = 2.(k-1) + f(a)+f(b)$$
$$a+b=k+1 $$
a,b are positive integers

We have to prove that $$f(x)\leq{x}^{2}$$ using induction for 1<=x<=k

So we will prove $$f(k+1)\leq{(k+1)}^{2}$$
When x=k+1,
$$f(k+1) = 2.(k-1) + f(a)+f(b)$$
$$f(k+1)\leq 2.(k-1) + {a}^{2}+{b}^{2}$$

How to proceed further?

Comment: Cannot be done with given information.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited it. Does it make sense now?

Comment: You can use \leq within $$ for $\leq$..

Comment: What are $a,b$? Are they positive integers?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Non-negative integers

Comment: How did you write $f(a) \leq a^{2}$?.  We may have $a=k+1,b=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that was what the problem required to prove. I am not sure about a,b being positive intergers or non-negative integers though

Comment: Can you show that $2(k-1) + a^2 + b^2 \leq (k+1)^2$? If so, you are done.